# Using Scrapy to crawl shopping store data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a shopping website for prices, using scrapy. Consider this code below, executed from scrapy shell for the website:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div[1]').extract()
```

The result is this:

```
[u'<div class="subcategory-title"><span class="placeholder"></span></div>']
```

But on the page source code (seen using chrome developer tools), I can see this for that line:

```
<div class="subcategory-title">Organic Vegetables</div>
```

First, how is it that the "Organic Vegetables" is hidden by the span? Second, how can I get the text instead of the empty span element?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you forgot to add `/text()` to your XPath

Comment: How can I achieve the same thing using BeautifulSoup and Request? That is instead of using Scrapy or Splash?

Comment: Just try to change your xpath to `//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/text()`

Answer (score 0):

You may be seeing a span because the text node is dynamically generated using JavaScript.

A library that works well with Scrapy such as Splash could help you scrape the desired page.

*For more information about this visit this link*:
[scrapy-splash usage for rendering javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262194/scrapy-splash-usage-for-rendering-javascript)